# Prove that a transformation is a diffeomorphism and a flow. Solution verification

Tags: solution-verification, diffeomorphism

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function, and $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function with compact support (i.e., vanishing outside a certain ball).

1. Justify that the transformation $$\Phi_t: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \ , \ \Phi_t(x) = x + t \cdot \phi(x)$$ is a diffeomorphism for $t$ in some interval $(-t_0, t_0)$. Determine the derivative of $\det D\Phi_t(x)$ with respect to $t$ at $t = 0$.
2. Show that the derivative of the function $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \ , \ f(t) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} F(x + t \cdot \phi(x)) dx$$ at $t = 0$ is $$f'(0) = -\int_{R^n} F(x) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_1}(x) + \cdots + \frac{\partial \phi_n}{\partial x_n}(x)\right) dx$$.

Hint: You can assume the formula $\det(I + tA) = 1 + t \cdot \operatorname{tr} A + o(t)$ is known.

SOLUTION:

(1)

To prove that $\Phi_t$ is a diffeomorphism for $t$ in some interval $(-t_0, t_0)$, we need to show that:

- $\Phi_t$ is differentiable and invertible,
- inverse of $\Phi_t$ is also differentiable.

**Differentiability of** $\Phi_t$:

$\Phi_t(x) = x + t \cdot \phi(x)$ is differentiable because it is the sum of differentiable functions ($x$ and $t \cdot \phi(x)$).

**Invertibility of** $\Phi_t$:

We know that $\Phi_0(x) = x$.

To show that $\Phi_t$ is invertible for $t$ in some interval $(-t_0, t_0)$, it is enough to show that $\det D\Phi_t(x) \neq 0$ for $t$ in this interval.

We have:

$$ D\Phi_t(x) = I + t \cdot D\phi(x), $$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. Now let's compute the derivative of $\det D\Phi_t(x)$ with respect to $t$ at $t = 0$:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \det D\Phi_t(x) \Big|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt} \det (I + t \cdot D\phi(x)) \Big|_{t=0} $$

Using Jacobi's theorem on determinant derivatives, we get:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \det (I + t \cdot D\phi(x)) \Big|_{t=0} = \text{tr}(D\phi(x)), $$

where $\text{tr}$ denotes the trace of the matrix.

Since $\text{tr}(D\phi(x))$ does not depend on $t$, we can choose a sufficiently small $t_0 > 0$ such that $\det D\Phi_t(x) \neq 0$ for $t \in (-t_0, t_0)$.

**Differentiability of the inverse** $\Phi_t^{-1}$:

Since $\Phi_t$ is differentiable and invertible, its inverse $\Phi_t^{-1}$ is also differentiable.

Therefore, $\Phi_t$ is a diffeomorphism for $t$ in some interval $(-t_0, t_0)$.

---

(2)

To show that $\Phi_t$ is a flow, we need to prove two properties:

1. $\Phi_0 = \text{id}$, where $\text{id}$ is the identity.
2. $\Phi_{s+t} = \Phi_s \circ \Phi_t$ for any $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Property (1) is obvious, since $\Phi_0(x) = x + 0 \cdot \phi(x) = x$.

Property (2) can be proven using the differentiability of $\Phi_t$ and the fact that $\Phi_t$ is a diffeomorphism for $t$ in some interval $(-t_0, t_0)$.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand how you get from the Jacobian being invertible to $\Phi_t$ is a invertible. Locally invertible does in general not imply global invertible (maybe I misunderstand your argument).

Comment: You mean the invertibility of $\Phi_t$? Isn't it enough to show that $\det D\Phi_t(x) \neq 0$ for $t$ in the interval where we need to have invertibility? @SeverinSchraven

Comment: Consider $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=(e^x \cos(y), e^x \sin(y)).$$ The differential never vanishes, but the map is not injective. Your argument would work for $n=1$.

Comment: Ok, nerver mind, it's wrong. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can show injectivity like this $$\Vert \Phi_t(x)-\Phi_t(y)\Vert \geq \Vert x-y\Vert - t \Vert \Phi(x)-\Phi(y)\Vert\geq \Vert x-y\Vert - t \sup_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Vert D\Phi\Vert \cdot \Vert x-y\Vert.$$ Now choose $t$ sufficiently small with respect to the differential and conclude.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I will edit that in a second. Could you tell me if you think that I did this one correctly? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664357/integration-solution-verification-i-need-to-know-if-my-thinking-is-correct

Comment: Your map is not a flow. Try to write out what $\Phi_s(\Phi_t(x))$ is equal to. For surjectivity we can proceed as follows. We know that $\Phi$ has compact support, say in a ball of radius $R$. Outside of this ball, $\Phi_s$ is just the identity. Consider now $S=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus Im(\Phi_t)$. We want to show that this set is empty. Pick a point $y_\infty\in \partial S$ (this is possible if $S$ is not empty). Then pick a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq Im(\Phi_t)$ such that $y_n \rightarrow y_\infty$ (this works as $y_\infty$ is on the boundary). [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Pick now $x_n\in B_{R}(0)$ such that $y_n=\Phi_t(x_n)$. By compactness, $(x_n)$ admits a converging subsequence $x_{n_m} \rightarrow x_\infty$ and we have $\Phi_t(x_\infty)=y_\infty$ as $\Phi_t$ is continuous. Thus, $y_\infty \in Im(\Phi_t)$. However, this gives a contradiction as by the inverse function theorem a whole neighborhood of $y_\infty$ needs to be contained in $Im(\Phi_t)$. Thus, $S$ must have been empty to begin with and our function is surjective.

Comment: Note that this would be true in more generality. The property that I used is called proper (preimages of compact sets are compact). See for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364690/f-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-is-diffeomorphism-iff-f-is-local-diffeomorphis This is a standard technique to upgrade local diffeomorphisms to global diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Also, your family does not really look like it has the flow property. We have $$ \Phi_s(\Phi_t(x)) = \Phi_t(x) + s\phi(\Phi_t(x)) = x+t\phi(x) + s\phi(x+t\phi(x)). $$ In general this has no reason to be equal to $x+(s+t)\phi(x)$. It would imply that $$ s\phi(x) = s\phi(x+t\phi(x))$$ for all $x$.